# How do we process only data that was last refreshed in a Materialize VIEW

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, materialized-views

We are using a Mview to fetch some data from another DB table to our DB. We need to perform 2 major tasks

1.Here we need to refresh the MView at specific time(i.e 6am and 7pm EST).

2.We have another stored procedure which uses these data and perform some insertion. But client needs only data should be processed based on the DATE column in the MVIEW. I.e it needs to insert only the lates inserted record or the data refreshed after the last MVIEW refresh.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW PPM_TFS_RECEIVED_MVIEW
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH COMPLETE
ON DEMAND
 START WITH SYSDATE
 NEXT SYSDATE + 1/12
 AS select * from v_TFSTaskIntegration@LHRxxx0D;
```

As of now i have made a refreshfor every 2 hours which i need to be altered.
My query is How do we get the latest MVIEW data/time and how do we staore the same to obtain the data that are >refrsed time
Please help me to sort this one out, as this been an clueless one for us.

Thanks,
Rash

Comment: got a solution myself!! .

Answer (score 0):

got a solution myself after help from oher sources!!

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TEST_DATA_RASH_MVIEW
 BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH COMPLETE
ON DEMAND
 START WITH SYSDATE
 NEXT SYSDATE + 1/12
 AS
select * from PPM_TFS_RECEIVED_MVIEW
where  "CreatedDate" > (SELECT last_refresh FROM ALL_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES WHERE NAME='PPM_TFS_RECEIVED_MVIEW');
```